# Python Broken Pipe Error

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import sys,os,random,subprocess,socket,threading,time
from queue import Queue

#Author Caleb Fahlgren
#Security Tool

#Home Window
class Window1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    #Menu Bar Widgets
#<----------------------------------------------------Server.Stream>
    #Packet sender Window Code
    def sendtcp(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Window2(self.newWindow)

    def sendUDP(self):
        self.newWindow2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = SendUDP(self.newWindow2)


    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Multipurpose Security Tool")
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
    #File Menu Code
    #<---------------------------------------------------->
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New",command=self.new)
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save")
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Save as")
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
    #<----------------------------------------------------->

    #Capture Menu Code
    #<----------------------------------------------------->
        captureMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,)

        #Submenu Send Packet
        #<----------------------------------------------------->
        submenu = Menu(captureMenu, tearoff=0)
        submenu.add_command(label="Send TCP Packet",command=self.sendtcp)
        submenu.add_command(label="Send UDP Packet", command=self.sendUDP)
        captureMenu.add_cascade(label="Send Packet", menu=submenu, underline=0)
        captureMenu.add_separator
        #<----------------------------------------------------->
        #Regular Menu Widgets under Capture
        captureMenu.add_separator()
        captureMenu.add_command(label="TCP Packet Analyzer")
        captureMenu.add_separator()
        captureMenu.add_command(label="UDP Packet Analyzer")
        captureMenu.add_separator()
        captureMenu.add_command(label="Whois Lookup")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Capture", menu=captureMenu)
    #<----------------------------------------------------->

    def showMenu(self, e):
        self.menu.post(e.x_root, e.y_root)

    #Exit Code on MenuBar
    def onExit(self):
        quitquestion = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Quit","Are you sure you want to quit?")
        if quitquestion == "yes":
            self.quit()

    #New Code on MenuBar
    def new(self):
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

#UDP Packet Sender
class Window2(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI2()

    #Exit Code on MenuBar
   def onExit(self):
       self.parent.destroy()

    #<----------------------------------------------------->
   def initUI2(self):
       self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
       menubar = Menu(self.parent)
       self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
       fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
       fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=self.onExit)
       menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
       self.parent.title("Send TCP Packet")
       self.parent.geometry("500x300+400+200")
       self.webaddresstcp = Entry(self, width=50,bg='gray')
       self.waltcp = Label(self,text="Address",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
       self.messagetcp = Entry(self, width=50,bg='gray')
       self.messagelabeltcp = Label(self, text="Message",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
       self.runbuttontcp=Button(self, text="Run",bg='green',activebackground="yellow",command=self.sendscripttcp)
       self.portnumbertcp = Entry(self,width=15,bg='gray')
       self.portlabeltcp = Label(self, text="Port",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
       self.waltcp.pack()
       self.webaddresstcp.pack()
       self.messagelabeltcp.pack()
       self.messagetcp.pack()
       self.portlabeltcp.pack()
       self.portnumbertcp.pack()
       self.runbuttontcp.pack()
       self.pack()

   def onExit(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

   def sendscripttcp(self):
```

This is where I want to send a tcp packet to an ip address and a port in which the user typed in the Entry box in the GUI window. But everytime I run it I get.

sock.sendto(bytes(TCPMESSAGE, "utf-8"), (TCP_IP, int(TCP_PORT)))
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

But when I run the UDP Script Packet Sender it works just fine. I also want to make sure I encode everything before I send it over. :)

```
    try:

        TCP_IP = socket.gethostbyname("%s" % (self.webaddresstcp.get()))
        TCP_PORT ="%s" % (self.portnumbertcp.get())
        TCPMESSAGE = "%s" % (self.messagetcp.get())
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # TCP
        sock.sendto(bytes(TCPMESSAGE, "utf-8"), (TCP_IP, int(TCP_PORT)))
        sock.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('TCP INFO', 'TCP Target IP ' + TCP_IP + '\n' + 'TCP Target Port: ' + TCP_PORT + '\n' + 'Packet Data: ' + TCPMESSAGE)
    except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Value Error','You did not input anything into entry boxes!')


class SendUDP(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI3()

    def initUI3(self):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.parent.title("Send UDP Packet")
        self.parent.geometry("500x300+400+200")
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        self.webaddress = Entry(self, width=50,bg='gray')
        self.wal = Label(self,text="Address",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
        self.message = Entry(self, width=50,bg='gray')
        self.messagelabel = Label(self, text="Message",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
        self.runbutton=Button(self, text="Run",bg='green',activebackground="yellow",command=self.sendscript)
        self.portnumber = Entry(self,width=15,bg='gray')
        self.portlabel = Label(self, text="Port",font=("Helvetica", 12),fg="green")
        self.wal.pack()
        self.webaddress.pack()
        self.messagelabel.pack()
        self.message.pack()
        self.portlabel.pack()
        self.portnumber.pack()
        self.runbutton.pack()
        self.pack()

    def onExit(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

    def sendscript(self):
        try:
            UDP_IP = socket.gethostbyname("%s" % (self.webaddress.get()))
            UDP_PORT ="%s" % (self.portnumber.get())
            MESSAGE = "%s" % (self.message.get())
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
            sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, int(UDP_PORT)))
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('UDP INFO', 'UDP Target IP ' + UDP_IP + '\n' + 'UDP Target Port: ' + UDP_PORT + '\n' + 'Packet Data: ' + MESSAGE)
            sock.close()
        except ValueError:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Value Error','You did not input anything into entry boxes!')

#Windows Settings
def main():
#<----------------------------------------------------->
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x480+400+100")
    app = Window1(root)
    #Page 1 and Page 2 Tab
    root.mainloop()
#<----------------------------------------------------->
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Stackoverflow server always run, starting a thread when you connect to server. Server never close connection, always user can close. You try connect to `None` server !

Comment: You can't use `sock.sendto` on an unconnected TCP socket. For TCP, after creating the socket, you must call `sock.connect` on the client side (and `sock.accept` on the server side) before you can successfully transmit data. (And it doesn't really make sense to use `sendto` at all on TCP sockets -- not even sure it works -- typically you use `send`.)